# Create POJO class parsing SimpleFramework XML using retrofit

Tags: android, xml, simple-framework

This my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Query xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/Schemas/CABS/1.0/RQ.xsd">
    <SearchGroup xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/Schemas/CABS/1.0/Common.xsd">
      <SearchCriteriaFullName contains="a" />
    </SearchGroup>
  </Query>
  <Response xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/Schemas/CABS/1.0/RQ.xsd" />
</CABS_ProviderSearch_RQ>
```

I have not found any tutorial for create that POJO, especially for that Response Class.

My Response class is empty like this:

```
public class Response {

   public Response(){

   }
}
```

but still rejected and get error. My log error:

> org.simpleframework.xml.transform.TransformException: Transform of
>   class com.blabla.models.Response not supported

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `@Default` annotation to your `Response` class, this will reduce the amount of work. Though it'll lack the settings for the attribute.

As this question doesn't contain much information, please add some details and what you've done so far.

Most of the use cases are listed in the documentation (see [Tutorial](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) and [Examples](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php)). If you are stuck somewhere, feel free to post any problems.